# Search Bar text field colors won't change

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield, uicolor

When I am trying to change the text color or the placeholder text color for the `textfield` of the search bar nothing happens.

The textfield is embedded in the search bar of the search controller.

This is the code that I am using:

```
let textField = self.searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as! UITextField

textField.textColor = .white
```

What I find interesting is that when I try to change the tint color it works:

```
textField.tintColor = .white
```

Does anyone have any idea why this might happen?

I am trying to make the text and the placeholder text colors white.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you do it:

```
let textField = searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
textField?.textColor = .white
textField?.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "Placeholder", attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.white])
```

So you start by getting the `textField` and setting the `textColor` then you set the `attributedPlaceholder` for your `textField`.

**Update:**
For your searchController just do this:

```
override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    let textField = self.searchController.searchBar.value(forKey: "searchField") as? UITextField
    textField?.textColor = .white
    textField?.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string: "1334", attributes: [NSAttributedStringKey.foregroundColor: UIColor.white])
}
```

Which will give you:
[image]
[image]

Comment: I tried this as well, but it doesn't do anything, the colors remain the same. The search bar is embedded into a nav bar, maybe it's because of that?

Comment: I’m gonna try to create a different search bar and then attribute it to the search controller

Comment: Do that and let me know how it worked out for you because above code worked fine for me.

Comment: the problem is I can't change the search bar of the search controller, it's a get-only property...

Comment: @FlorinAlexandru, you can. I have created a sample project that shows you how I have done it. You can download it [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jggx12ywp94ib3j/SearchBar.zip?dl=0&m=), not that I have set the colors to green in this test example.

Comment: @FlorinAlexandru, did it help you?

Comment: sorry for the late reply, the code you sent gets the searchBar from a Storyboard, mine is instantiated from the search controller

Comment: @FlorinAlexandru, it still works on a searchController. Check the update of how to do that.

Comment: for some reason it doesn't work in my app... I appreciate your effort but these are the same solutions I found in other answers and they don't work...

Answer (score 0):

To change your placeHolder color for your textView :

```
textField.attributedPlaceholder = NSAttributedString(string:"Your placeholder", 
attributes: [NSForegroundColorAttributeName: //your color])
```

Some explanations. You need to access the property `attributedPlaceholder` for a `UItextField` to target the placeholder of your textField. Then, you need to add an attribute to your placeholder. In your case, this attribute is `NSForegroundColorAttributeName` which controls the foregound color. Finally just put a `UIColor` like UIColor.white...

Comment: It does nothing ?

Comment: exactly, that's what happens when I try to set the text color as well, the only thing that works is when I change the tint color

Comment: Maybe because of the search bar

Comment: Ok, but isn’t there a way to change the text color and placeholder text color in case of a textfield inside of a search bar?

Comment: Did you try using storyboard ?

Comment: I create the search controller programmatically...I’ll try to create one in storyboard as well

Comment: But I don't see any option to change the placeholder text color in storyboard